# How do I set the small and large font size boundaries for a tag cloud?

Tags: css

Here is my code but I’m trying to come up with a way to set the range from say 50% to 150% of the default font size.

```
<ul class="tags">
            {#each tags as tag}
                <li style={`font-size: ${(tag.count / tags[0].count) * 100 + 100}%;`}>
                    {tag.word} ({tag.count})
                </li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say the font size base is 50% and your biggest font size is 150%.

We can have this formula `50 + (current tag count / total tag count)*100`

Some scenarios:
**Scenario 1**

Tag 1 = 50

Tag 2 = 50

Total tags = 100

Tag 1's font size is (50+(50/100)*100)= 100 which is `100%`

Tag 2's font size is (50+(50/100)*100)= 100 which is `100%`

**Scenario 2**

Tag 1 = 50

Tag 2 = 90

Tag 3 = 20

Total tags = 160

Tag 1's font size is (50+(50/160)*100)= 81.25 which is `81.25%`

Tag 2's font size is (50+(90/160)*100)= 106.25 which is `106.25%`

Tag 3's font size is (50+(20/160)*100)= 62.5 which is `62.5%`

**Scenario 3**

Tag 1 = 0

Tag 2 = 0

Tag 3 = 20

Total tags = 20

Tag 1's font size is (50+(0/20)*100)= 50 which is `50%`

Tag 2's font size is (50+(0/20)*100)= 50 which is `50%`

Tag 3's font size is (50+(20/20)*100)= 150 which is `150%`

Comment: I think I’m looking for the upper and lower bounds to be static. So whatever the highest count is would be 150% and the lowest count tag would be 50%

Comment: I’ve some other examples that use a 1-8 weighting value. So 8 would be 150% or 32pt. Whatever. And 1 would be 50% or say 12pt.

Comment: You can define classes that are mapped with your font size scales. For example: `tag-font-size-1` (font-size: 12pt) to `tag-font-size-8` (font-size: 32pt). And apply this formula `(current tag count / total tag count)*8` (8 is your total scales) to find `x` in `tag-font-size-x`. For example, using the above scenario 1's data, `(50/100)*8 = 4` which is `tag-font-size-4`, if it's not an integer value, you can round it. If the calculation is 0, we can set default font size 12pt.
If you want to find the highest or lowest value for font size, I think you need to apply other logic to check.

Comment: that gives me way more than 8 scales doing `<li class={\`tag-size-${(tag.count / tags[0].count) * 8}\`}>` -- i'm size .tag-size-52
`

Comment: You meant your biggest tag size will be `tag-size-52`?

Comment: Yes that so correct. Not just 1-8